# calling controller function from link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am trying to call a function in controller from link function. From controller function, I have to call a rest service call. (I tried calling rest service from link function , But I didn't get success. So I am trying to call controller function from link and from there I will call rest service).

My code is as below.

```
app.directive('collection', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            collection: '=',
            articleData: '=',
            articleContent: '='
        },
        template: "<ul><member ng-repeat='member in collection' member='member' article-data='articleData' article-content='articleContent'></member></ul>"
    }
});

app.directive('member', function($compile,$http) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            member: '=',
            articleData: '=',
            articleContent: '='
        },
        template: "<div><li><a href='#' ng-click='getContent(member.itemId)'>{{member.title}}</a></li></div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.getContent = function(itemId) {

                 scope.testFunction(itemId);
            }

            if (angular.isArray(scope.member.tocItem)) {
                if (scope.member.hasChildren == "true") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < scope.member.tocItem.length; i++) {
                        if (scope.member.tocItem.title) {
                            scope.member.tocItem.title.hide = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                element.append("<collection collection='member.tocItem'></collection>");    
                $compile(element.contents())(scope)
            }
        }
    }
});

app.controller('apdController', function($scope, getTocService,$location) {
    var bookId = $location.search().id;
    var sampdata = getTocService.getToc(bookId);
    $scope.tasks =sampdata;
    //$scope.tasks = data;

    var artData = getTocService.getArtData('PH1234');
    $scope.articleContent = artData;

    $scope.testFunction = function(itemId){
         alert("called.....");
        }
});
```

Here, I am trying to call testFunction from link.From testFunction, I am planning to call a rest service. But getting undefined is not a function error. 
Can someone please help? Also, please let me know is this a right approach (from link function to controller and from controller to rest call . Since my time line is less, I couldn't think of some other approach)

Comment: Take a look at `$emit` and/or `$broadcast`, that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

What does `testFunction` do? You have different options. If `testFunction` calls a rest service then you should definitely move it to a service.

```
app.factory('restService', function($http) {
    function testFunction(itemId){
       // Whatever you need
       return $http.get('myUrl');
    } 

    return  {
       testFunction: testFunction
    }
});
```

Then inject it in your directive

```
app.directive('member', function($compile, $http, restService) {
    ...
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.getContent = function(itemId) {
             restService.testFunction(itemId);
        }

        ....
    }
});
```

This way, you can also call it in your controller if you ever need it.
If instead you have to communicate something to the controller then you can use signals.

Comment: from testFunction I will call service. AS of now, I have put an alert to see control is coming to that method.

Comment: you can put the alert inside restService